COBOL program has a faulty check
I have the following COBOL program:
At the end, I ask the user if the results are "Good Enough."
However, no matter what I type, it always says: "Cool, glad you like it!"
Even when I type "N".
Why would it not recognize that?
Thanks!
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. RANDOM-STRING-MAKER.
   
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
   SPECIAL-NAMES.
       CRT STATUS IS KEYBOARD-STATUS.
   
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 MY-RANDOM-STRING    PIC X(202).
   01 STRING-LENGTH       PIC 999 COMP.
   01 CHAR-SET            PIC X(62) VALUE
       "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".
   01 CHAR-SET-LEN        PIC 99 COMP VALUE 62.
   01 I                   PIC 999 COMP.
   01 RAND-IDX            PIC 999 COMP.
   01 SEED                PIC 9(8) COMP.
   01 CURRENT-TIME        PIC 9(8).
   01 USER-ANSWER         PIC X.
   01 KEYBOARD-STATUS.
       05 KEY-STAT-1      PIC 99.
       05 KEY-STAT-2      PIC 99.
   
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-PROC.
       PERFORM INIT-RANDOM
       PERFORM MAKE-RANDOM-STRING
       PERFORM SHOW-RESULT
       STOP RUN.

   INIT-RANDOM.
       ACCEPT CURRENT-TIME FROM TIME
       COMPUTE SEED = FUNCTION MOD (CURRENT-TIME, 10000000) + 1.

   MAKE-RANDOM-STRING.
       COMPUTE STRING-LENGTH = FUNCTION RANDOM (SEED) * 108 + 95
       PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I > STRING-LENGTH
           COMPUTE RAND-IDX = FUNCTION RANDOM * CHAR-SET-LEN + 1
           MOVE CHAR-SET (RAND-IDX:1) TO MY-RANDOM-STRING (I:1)
       END-PERFORM.

   SHOW-RESULT.
       DISPLAY "Here's your random string:"
       DISPLAY MY-RANDOM-STRING (1:STRING-LENGTH)
       DISPLAY "It's " STRING-LENGTH " characters long."
       DISPLAY "Good enough? (Y/N)"
       ACCEPT USER-ANSWER
       IF USER-ANSWER = "Y" OR "y"
           DISPLAY "Cool, glad you like it!"
       ELSE
           DISPLAY "Aw, too bad. Maybe try running it again?"
       END-IF.


It seems to be missing a THEN - in IF [condition] THEN ...  Perhaps the conditions on that line should also be in parenthesis - like: IF (USER-ANSWER = "Y" OR "y") THEN

@blurfus THEN is a noise word, it doesn't matter if you have it or not, parenthesis are only useful if you scope something, but here it is a quite simple expression with a single OR, so no need to use these either

Please add the information about the compiler/environment where you've tested that to your question (that can have a difference for the answers).

Testing with both GnuCOBOL and GCC-COBOL, I get the expected result: https://godbolt.org/z/nYMoT1qh5 (note: I've dropped the unused key status as that wasn't used and gcobol had issues with it)

I agree with @SimonSobisch, we need more details about compiler/environment to  investigate; meanwhile do you mind to try adding another IF before the existing, and modify that one, like bellow?
IF USER-ANSWER = "y"
    MOVE "Y" TO USER-ANSWER
END-IF.
IF USER-ANSWER = "Y"
    DISPLAY "Cool, glad you like it!"
ELSE
    DISPLAY "Aw, too bad. Maybe try running it again?"
END-IF.


Try adding . directly after ACCEPT USER-ANSWER; ie. ACCEPT USER-ANSWER.
